# Randomized Quick Sort Implementation in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm

I just started learning C++, and I'm taking an algorithms course on MIT Open Course Ware to get a better understanding of basic CS and the best practices in C++. Any comments on the structure of the algorithm (optimizations, etc) or best practices in C++ would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include <iterator>
#include <random>

namespace sort
{

    namespace detail
    {
        template <typename ForwardIter, typename Compare>
        ForwardIter randomized_partition(ForwardIter start, ForwardIter end, Compare less_than)
        {
            static std::default_random_engine gen;
            std::uniform_int_distribution<long> rand_index(0, std::distance(start, end) - 1);

            ForwardIter pivot = start + rand_index(gen);
            std::iter_swap(start, pivot);
            pivot = start;

            ForwardIter less_than_pivot = start, greater_than_pivot = start + 1;
            while (greater_than_pivot != end)
            {
                if ( less_than(*greater_than_pivot, *pivot) ) {
                    ++less_than_pivot;
                    std::iter_swap(less_than_pivot, greater_than_pivot);
                }
                ++greater_than_pivot;
            }

            std::iter_swap(pivot, less_than_pivot);
            pivot = less_than_pivot;
            return pivot;
        }
    }


    template <typename ForwardIter, typename Compare = std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIter>::value_type>>
    void randomized_quick_sort(ForwardIter start, ForwardIter end, Compare less_than = Compare())
    {
        if (std::distance(start, end) > 1)
        {
            ForwardIter pivot = sort::detail::randomized_partition(start, end, less_than);
            randomized_quick_sort(start, pivot, less_than);
            randomized_quick_sort(pivot + 1, end, less_than);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Nitpick: You might want to call your comparing function something else than `less_than` since people might want to sort by a different key. I think `std::sort` uses `comp` as its parameter name.

Comment: Also, forward iterators are not required to provide an `operator+`, so `start + 1` should be replaced with `std::next(start)`. The same goes for `start + rand_index(gen);`.

Comment: Thanks! I did some reading on iterator types and included your suggestions and a `static_assert` to ensure the passed iterator's category inherited from `std::forward_iterator_tag`. Anything else that I could improve on?